# Saving segue passed managedObjectContext in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

say i have one view controller (VCA), which segues to another another view controller (VCB). while preparing to segue, VCA passes its managedObjectContext (i.e. following the "tell don't ask" convention). VCA also has a function `saveManagedObjectContext()` that performs the saving and error handling.

so, in VCA:

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

...

func saveManagedObjectContext() {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

...

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    ...

    if let vcb = segue.destinationViewController as? VCB {
        vcb.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
    }

    ...

}
```

and in VCB:

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
```

say VCB adds some entity to the managedObjectContext that was passed to it from VCA

```
func createSomeEntity() {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("SomeEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    something = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as? SomeEntity
}
```

is there any (correct) way to call the `saveManagedObjectContext()` function from VCA rather than having to copy the function over to VCB?

thanks

Comment: Instead of passing the managed object context you could pass the application delegate instance to be able to have access to the entire Core data stack, but – since you're using the way to retrieve the reference to application delegate in VCA anyway – pass nothing and do the same in VCB. Consider also to use a shared singleton class to manage the Core Data stuff.

Comment: i was reading that it was "schematically bad" to keep asking for the managed object context from the app delegate in different view controllers and you should instead pass a reference of it from the top, i.e. the "tell don't ask" methodology...

Comment: Yes, but you're already breaking the rule in VCA ;-)

Comment: sure - but VCA could have been my root controller or passed the context from the app delegate `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ... then this would be okay?

Comment: Yes, that's a good place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is a singleton class.

Create a new Swift file, replace the predefined code with

```
class CoreDataManager: NSObject {

  // MARK: - Shared Instance

  class var sharedManager : CoreDataManager {
    struct Singleton {
      static let instance = CoreDataManager()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
  }

  // MARK: - Core Data stack

  lazy var ...

}
```

and then replace `lazy var ...` with the entire Core Data stack from AppDelegate.

Now you can access Core Data from everywhere using

```
let managedObjectContext = CoreDataManager.sharedManager.managedObjectContext
```

or to call the save action

```
CoreDataManager.sharedManager.saveAction(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Good point about "tell don't ask". A lot of Apple sample code evangelizes this concept. **However**, in recent years, Apple has also provided sample code with a Core Data stack class that handles the object graph, practically **abandoning the "tell don't ask" pattern**.

Also, in many popular and acclaimed open source projects, this pattern is used. In most cases you reduce the code and still have a robust solution. For example, in more complex projects with nested background contexts it is often the only feasible setup.

Thus, I would recommend to create a `CoreDataManager` class that handles the core data stack, or for less complex apps (single, main thread context) use the app delegate.

Note that in Swift, you can really make this very concise with global variables (which you should use sparingly!). E.g., on top of the `AppDelegate.swift` you could write

```
let SharedAppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
```

(I like to capitalize my global singletons). You can use this as follows

```
do { try SharedAppDelegate.context.save() } catch {}
```

Comment: sorry - how does this conform to "tell don't ask" if i'm always asking for the `ShareAppDelegate`? so in VCA i get a reference to the context by `let managedObjectContext = SharedAppDelegate.managedObjectContext` and then in VCB i have to do the same thing... or do i get one managed context reference from the offset, pass it around to subsequent view controllers, then save using the `SharedAppDelegate.saveContext()` function in any of the view controllers where needed? thanks

Comment: It does not. That's my point. "tell don't ask" has been all but abandoned by Apple itself.

Comment: okay - miscommunication. so to confirm: you and @vadian recommend ditching the "tell don't ask" method and just create instances on the fly or access the `SharedAppDelegate` singleton directly?

Comment: Yes, or a separate class as mentioned. You could even go further and define a global function `saveObejctGraph()`. ;-)